# Delaying- conversion

Tags: conversion

I am currently a chrisitan who is a minor though I dont believe in the religion because I know islam is the truth after proper research, and I wish to follow my newfound faith. But I know my familly will not take this well as they are very religious people. Should I delay my conversion till I am older? This means Ill be forced to take part in christian rituals and traditions which I dont believe in but then again it doesn't feel right delaying my duty to Allah. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Don't delay it, even if you fail to practice it properly, it's still infinitely better for you to convert and testify to the First Commandment, that God is one.

If you are currently Christian, this is the most important commandment from Jesus and I think Jesus knows what's better for you than your parents

“The most important one,” answered Jesus, “is this: ‘Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, the Lord is one.
Mark 12:29

Regarding your duties Islamically, you may not be able to do them or you may be able to, I don't know your situation. I would suggest trying to find some local Muslims in your area who are trustworthy who can help you navigate that tricky situation. I can't tell how your parents would react to you losing faith in Christianity or (worse in their minds probably) entering Islam. However staying a private believer is still infinitely better. If they command you to invoke Jesus as god or lord or command you to testify to that, just flat out refuse whatever the consequences are and trust God. I commend you for your faith and I hope our Lord increases it in you and guides you by it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you believe Islam is truth, you can take the [shahada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada) yourself now itself. By taking the shahada you are only reverting to the original monotheistic faith of prophet Abraham.

You can conceal your faith if you fear it can be harmful for you to reveal it now. There is a story about a person who concealed his faith in the Quran. see https://quran.com/en/ghafir/28

Then you can learn about the five pillars of Islam https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Pillars_of_Islam and gradually increase your knowledge of Islam and also start practicing it.